# How do I listen to 5.1 audio properly when my latop/headphones are only 2.0?

Tags: audio, dvd, 5.1

A while back I was wondering why my dvd was so quiet on my computer then solved it by chosing the 2.0 track instead of the 5.1 track.

But now I have a DVD which only has 5.1, how can I watch it without losing the other channels?

If it helps, I'm using Media Player Classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 5.1 track on the dvd, then set the output in the sound driver to stereo.  it should mux the front and rear channels together in hardware.  if it doesn't get a better soundcard

Comment: What sound card? It's a laptop. :P Guess I should have mentioned that. :P

Comment: XD, they do have usb/expresscard/pcmcia sound devices for laptop gamers

Comment: Well I just mean normal stock laptop with no niceties.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VLC there is quite a few audio tweaks you can do, but in the standard Audio menu you can choose between 5.1, 2 front 2 rear, stereo and mono.

I only had a quick look around the preferences so there might be something even better among the many settings. To get to the cool/advanced menus be sure to click the `All` radio-button indicated in the picture.

[image]